# How to get the value from textbox & dropdown without submit

Tags: php

I want to pass the value of product id, product name, textbox & drop down to 'addtocart.php' page. Only values I managed to get are id & name.
If I use form for these then values of product id & name are not submitting.
Can anyone help sending values of textbox & dropdown as well?

```
while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_array($results)){

                print
                "<div class= 'item'>" .
                "<p>Product id ".$row["id"]."</p>".
                "<p><img src=".$row["image_location"]." class='masterTooltip' id='b7' title='Double click on image to make as favorite' ondblclick='openlink({$row["id"]})'></p>".
                "<p>&pound".$row["price"]."</p>".
                "<p>".$row["name"]."</p>".
                "<p>".
                "Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity' style='width: 20px; height:14px;'>".
                "&nbsp;<select name='type'>".
                "<option value='KiloGrams'>KiloGrams</opstion>".
                "<option value='Bunch'>Bunch</option>".
                "</select>".
                "<p>".      
                "<a href='addtocart.php?id={$row["id"]}&name={$row["name"]}' class='button' id='b1'> Buy Now</a>".
            //  "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='addtofavorite.php?id={$row["id"]}&name={$row["name"]}' id='heart'></a>".
                "</p>".
                "</div>";
```

Comment: why don't you, simply, submit the form?

Comment: Submitting form doesn't include $row["id"] value somehow, can you suggest something?

Comment: you can use ajax or javascript

Comment: You can submit id by adding one more line '<input type="hidden" name="id" value"'.$row->id.'" />'

Comment: you code has errors : `"<a href='addtocart.php?id={$row["id"]}&name={$row["name"]}' class='button' id='b1'> Buy Now</a>".`

Comment: I tried using document.getElementById("quantity") & storing that in a variable, but as these products are coming from database & there are lost of products, page stops at first product itself & doesn't display the rest of them.

Comment: @ManZzup: I don't think there is an error in that particular line because it's working perfectly fine, it's adding values 'id & name' to database without any issues.

Comment: srry my baad i didnt see the {} wrapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sumbit the form using the `<input type='hidden' name='your_field_name' value='your_field_value' />` for those fields that aren't in any other input but that you want to send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ajax, I don't know if used it before but it works like this;
  First you need to listen change event then send request to server;

```
$( "#type" ).change(function() {
 $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      context: this.val()
       }).done(function() {
            alert("it worked");
            });
       });
```

I hope you I could express it well.